# Connect and run unix commands on remote server Progress Openedge

Tags: unix, command, remote-server, openedge, progress-4gl

I need to connect to ***remote server via sftp*** and ***put*** some file there. Following commands do my work from terminal:

```
sftp -P <port> user@remote_server
cd <target_dir_at_remote_server>
put <my_file_at_local_server>
quit
```

Here, first line establishes the connection to the remote server and following commands are run there.
**But** when i try to run these commands from Progress 4GL code using `os-command value(<commands>)` or `unix value(<commands>)`, ***all commands run on local server*** instead of remote server.
Suggestions with code sample will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running remotely via Appserver or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never ran into this specifically but I'd guess Progress is not keeping context of your chain of commands. I suggest one of these two:

Piping them in a single statement with '|' as in 'ls -l | more' 
or, if that doesn't work,

creating a shell script and saving your file locally, then running that with the file location and name you want to upload as a parameter, and finally deleting the local file.

Comment: Piping in a single statement with "|" like below worked: `echo put <my_file_at_local_server> | sftp -P <port> user@remote_server:<target_dir_at_remote_server>`. Thanks a lot @bupereira.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not individual "commands" from an OS-COMMAND perspective.  "sftp" is the command and "cd", "put", and "quit" are input to sftp.  Typically you would use a "here document", redirect input from a file containing that input or write a script as a wrapper for that sort of thing.

Use scp instead of sftp.  That will completely avoid the need to give input to the utility.  It is much simpler:

```
scp my_file user@remote.server:/remotedir
```